# How do I correctly paginate in Hibernate with nested objects with ManyToMany associations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, jax-rs

Ok, so I have the following (abbreviated) 3 entity and HibernateUtil classes.

```
public class Tag {
    @Id
    BigDecimal id;

    String tag

    @ManyToMany( mappedBy="tags" )
    List<Label> labels;
}

public class Label {
    @Id
    BigDecimal id;

    String label;

    @ManyToMany( targetEntity=Tag.class )
    List<Tag> tags;
}

public class Data {
    @Id
    BigDecimal id;

    BigDecimal data;

    @ManyToOne
    Label label;
}


public class HibernateUtil {

    public static List pagedQuery(DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria, Integer start, Integer size) throws WebApplicationException {
        Session session = getSession();
        try {
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            List records = detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session)
                    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                    .setFirstResult(start)
                    .setMaxResults(size)
                    .list();

            transaction.commit();

            return records;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // Place Logger here...
            throw new WebApplicationException(e);
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

The issue I have is that when I try to query the Data class with the HibernateUtil.pagedQuery( detatchedCriteria, start, size ), my result list doesn't match the size parameter. I have found that the reason for this is the way hibernate builds the query to include the tags (Data.Label.Tags).

For instance, when a Label has more than one associated Tags the result list for the Data object subquery used in the complete paginated query would look like the following (I found this by parsing the sql Hibernate spits out to the console)

1. Data-1;Label:Tag-1
2. Data-1;Label;Tag-2
3. Data-2;Label;Tag-1
4. Data-2;Label;Tag-2
5. etc...

If I were to call this with size=3, then the returned result set would be

1. Data-1;Label:Tag-1
2. Data-1;Label;Tag-2
3. Data-2;Label;Tag-1

However, Hibernate would then group the first two rows together (since they're the same Data object), and my returned List object would have a size of 2 (Data-1 & Data-2)

I attempted to replace the setResultTransformer method with a Projection approach that I found through Google, but that then only returned the id's of the Data objects.

Does anyone have any advice for me? I'm not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a common problem paginating with hibernate. The resultTransformer is applied in the "Java" side, so the pagination has already been made on the DB side.

The simplest (maybe not the most optimized) is to do two queries, one with the projection and pagination (like the one you already did) and another using the projection id's. Here is an example:

```
//get the projection    
Criteria criteria = factory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(getEntityClass());
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct((Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.id()).add(Projections.property("name")))));
//paginate the results
    criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    criteria.setFirstResult(first);

List<Object[]> idList = criteria.list();
//get the id's from the projection
        List<Long> longList = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for (Object[] long1 : idList) {
            Object[] record = long1;
            longList.add((Long) record[0]);
        }

if (longList.size() > 0) {
//get all the id's corresponding to the projection, 
//then apply distinct root entity
            criteria = factory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(getEntityClass());
            criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", longList));
            criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        } else {
//no results, so let's ommit the second query to the DB
            return new ArrayList<E>();
        }

return criteria.list();
```

Comment: Interesting... do you know of any way to run the Projection as a subquery for the Restrictions.in constraint? That wouldn't escape the dual queries, but would eliminate the dual sql calls. It doesn't look like Restrictions.in() can take a Critria, so I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: I tried it with no luck, adding the projection to the criteria will result in the field number being reduced to the projection fields... I also tried to avoid the awful for to extract the long values, but the Restrictions.in need a typed list of the PK type (Long in my case). Please post it here if you find out how to avoid the dual query!

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll keep looking today, and if I find anything I'll definitely post it up here.

Comment: After much searching, I think the dual query is the only way to go. Restrictions.in() can't take a Criteria. I also looked into creating an alias, passing in a Property and trying to add a subquery to that by passing in a DetachedCriteria as the subquery. However, I found out that neither setMaxResults() and setFirstResult() can be be applied to DetachedCriteria. They can only be used on Criteria. Eventually I gave up, coded your solution, and started drinking heavily. Cheers